# Angular 2 & hammer js

Tags: angular, swipe

I don't know why but hammer-js  doesn't work at all with my angular 2 project and it doesn't show any mistakes.

This is how I connect it to project

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
<script>
TouchEmulator();
</script>
```

and Then I just put  (swiperight)="test()" to my html tag but nothing happen when I try swipe it.
Test function has just console.log()

Comment: can look at this post https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should change module file but I need just swipe left  event

Comment: Well I fixed it and its work but is it any possible way somehow connect it to HostListener? It would be really cool

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do

```
npm install hammerjs
```

then you would go to `your app.module.ts` and do:

```
import 'hammerjs'
```

This tutorial might guide you further on your quest: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2

Comment: Well I fixed it and its work but is it any possible way somehow connect it to HostListener? It would be really cool